# Strange Exception Handling in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

I'm trying to understand the exception handling in PL/pgSQL but ...

Case 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ins ()
AS $$ DECLARE
i INT;
BEGIN
insert into scott.emp (empno) values (9000);
commit;
i:=1/0;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
--rollback;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

call ins();
```

I would guess the line is inserted, but it is not

CASE 2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ins ()
AS $$ DECLARE
i INT;
BEGIN
insert into scott.emp (empno) values (9000);
commit;
--i:=1/0;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
--rollback;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

call ins();
```

Now, there is no div by zero , but alos no line in the table

Case 3:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ins ()
    AS $$ DECLARE
    i INT;
    BEGIN
    insert into scott.emp (empno) values (9000);
    commit;
    --i:=1/0;
    --EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --rollback;
    END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    call ins();
```

Now the line is inserted. It seems that the Problen is my Exception Block, but why?

Thanks in advance.
Marco

Comment: Read full explanation here: [Can a Postgres Commit Exist in Procedure that has an Exception Block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406735/can-a-postgres-commit-exist-in-procedure-that-has-an-exception-block)

Answer (score 4):

Silently throwing away your error message certainly does make debugging difficult.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ins ()
AS $$ DECLARE
i INT;
BEGIN
insert into scott.emp (empno) values (9000);
commit;
--i:=1/0;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
raise notice E'%', SQLERRM;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Shows:

```
NOTICE:  cannot commit while a subtransaction is active
```

So this due to the [documented limitation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html):

> A transaction cannot be ended inside a block with exception handlers.