# Transaction commit error - invalid transaction terminations

Tags: postgresql, postgres-11

Can you please guide what is wrong with below code which gives an issue with below error:

ERROR: invalid transaction termination.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "app"."sproc_data_create"
( name varchar(100))
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
Declare idIdentity int;
 BEGIN

 INSERT INTO data(Name) VALUES (name) RETURNING Id into idIdentity;
 INSERT INTO relationalData(dataId) VALUES (idIdentity);
  
 COMMIT; 
 END
```

For below scenarios, this does not work executing commit for one insert statement and expected to rollback second insert statement. This rollback both insert statements.

```
BEGIN
    
     INSERT INTO data(Name) VALUES (name) RETURNING Id into idIdentity;
     COMMIT;
    INSERT INTO relationalData(dataId) VALUES (idIdentity);
END
```

Execute below script:

```
/*
do
begin
    CALL "app"."sproc_data_create"("name field")
    
end
*/    
//invalid transaction termination
    CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function
```

Comment: ERROR:  "ididentity" is not a known variable

Comment: ERROR:  column "name field" does not exist

Comment: Apologies, have not created online sandbox. But this same scenario happen with my procedure and raising "invalid transaction termination" issue. By searching I found, "commit" outside of END statement but still that not worked. In SQL Server, it went so easy and I am new to postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Found an issue, I was executing "call" procedure statement inside DO BEGIN/END statement and that creates parent transaction scope.

As found on below post. (Basically, "call" has parent transaction scope and I use commit/rollback under subTransaction scope within procedure.
By removing DO BEGIN/END wrapper from "call" statement, it resolves the issue.

[Can a Postgres Commit Exist in Procedure that has an Exception Block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406735/can-a-postgres-commit-exist-in-procedure-that-has-an-exception-block)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error happened after trying to execute the stored procedure using sqlalchemy with python.

The main reason of this error was I created the stored procedure with including **`COMMIT;`** statement after **`INSERT/UPDATE`** statement, so replacing the stored procedure **without** using the **`COMMIT;`** statement solved the issue.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_files(
    file_id text)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO files(file_id)
                    VALUES (file_id);
        
-- AVOID USING COMMIT; HERE
    
END
$BODY$;

ALTER PROCEDURE insert_files(text)
    OWNER TO user;
```